# How can I change the gutter's background colors in atom

Tags: colors, atom-editor, appearance

How can I change [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMzs2.png) background colors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution.
You should edit these less attributes in `styles.less` (usually in the file `~/.atom/styles.less`)

```
atom-text-editor::shadow .gutter {
    background-color: #282828;
}
atom-text-editor::shadow .gutter .line-number {
    background-color: #282828;
}
```

I hope someone it will be useful

Answer (score 5):

After lot of search, This is what worked for me..   Go to tab Packages -> settings view -> manage themes. On top you see an option - you can also style Atom by editing *your stylesheet*. Click this and edit the settings css as needed. There is already a tag available as

atom-text-editor {
..
}
Inside this one, i gave values 
Color: black;
background-color: white;

Answer (score 4):

Go to atom install directory, default is .atom in the $HOME directory, open styles.less

Here is my final configuration, which gave me lighter background:

```
// style the background color of the tree view
.tree-view {
  //background-color: whitesmoke;
}

// style the background and foreground colors on the atom-text-editor element itself
atom-text-editor {
    color: #404040;
    background-color: #FFFAED;
}

// To style other content in the text editor's shadow DOM, use the::shadow expression
atom-text-editor::shadow .cursor {
  //border-color: red;
}
```

To customize colors to your taste refer to HEX RGB values at 
http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

Tested with

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Atom   1.12.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add :
styles.less is located under 
c:\Users\youruser\.atom\styles.less

Answer (score 0):

Go to Packages->setting views-> manage themes-> UI theme

Change the UI theme to **ONE LIGHT**

Change the Syntax theme to **ONE LIGHT**

Comment: Also you can go to themes through:
Edit -> Preferences -> Themes

Comment: @SalmaGomaa, Agree with you

Answer (score 0):

The background can be easily changed through the menu:

ATOM -> Preferences -> Themes -> Choose a theme

You can set UI theme and Syntax theme.

Atom Dark,
Atom Light,
One Dark,
One Light,
...